# Invalid form key on admin login

Tags: admin, login, forms, magento-1.14

Attempting to get a magento 1.14 site setup in Vagrant.

Store seems to be loading correctly, I'm able to view the frontend, admin login screen and n98magerun let's me edit conglfigs, clear caches etc.

I'm getting the dreaded "invalid form key" error when trying to login via the admin.

Here's what I've tried:

- made new admin user
- set PHP max input vars to 10000
- cleared browser cookies etc
- tried incognito mode
- tried another browser
- deleted var/cache and var/session
- checked form key is in the login form and is being sent in the request
- deleted cookie domain and cookie path config options

These are the typical suggestions and now I'm out of options.